# Idea IntelliJ 14.0.3 setup with play framework

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

What I did:

```
activator new firstApp simple-rest-scala
cd firstApp
```

then imported firstApp folder to intelliJ IDEA. I can see .idea folder created and firstApp.iml created. Is that fine?

now the issue is I see red in the code:

[image]

What configuration I am missing, how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have ultimate version of IntelliJ or community?

Comment: I have community one.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to have the Scala plugin installed.

If no project is currently open in IntelliJ IDEA, click Import Project on the Welcome screen.

If you've opened another project before select

File | New | Project from Existing Sources

and choose your project folder.

The Import Project Wizard should be open now in both cases.

On the first page of the Import Project wizard, select 
"Import project from external model" and choose SBT.

After selecting "Finish" on the next page your project should be imported correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with [the editions comparison matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), Play Framework is supported only in the Ultimate Edition. You can install the Scala plugin in community edition, but it won't work with a Play project. That's why your IDE highlights the syntax with red color.